# Kali Linux Networking not disabled by default?

Tags: networking, kali-linux

For some reason when I installed Kali the networking services and interfaces were all enabled. I know how disable the network manager at boot, but I am unsure if that is everything. Are the interfaces still enabled? How can I disable everything at boot, including dhcp.